# Cannot edit html through dynamic id created while implementing accordian

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am creating dynamic html table from an api response data.
Then I am trying to get info of each row text by another api response.
I want to show this response as jquery accordian.
But this needs div tag to be assigned dynamic id (which is same as row's text). But when I am trying to modify div content through jquery nothing is happening on screen.

```
<style>
    button.accordion {
        background-color: #eee;
        color: #444;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }

    button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    div.panel {
        padding: 0 18px;
        background-color: white;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }

</style>


<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Key</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tbody">
</tbody>
</table>


function populateTable(data) {

        $('#tbody').html("");
        for (var key in data) {
    var eachrow = '<tr>'
                +'<td><button id="'+ key+'" class="accordion" onclick="accod()">'+ key+'</button>'
        +'<div class="panel" id="'+key+'_panel">'
                +'<p>Some Text.</p></div>'+ '</td>'
                + '</tr>';
            $('#tbody').append(eachrow);
    }
}

function accod() {
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        $('button.accordion').on('click', function(e) {
            console.log(this.id);
            getData(""+this.id);
        });

        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].onclick = function() {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                if (panel.style.maxHeight){
                    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
                } else {
                    panel.style.maxHeight = 200 + "px";
                }
            }
        }

    }


function getData(key){

        $.getJSON("getData", {key :key}, function(data) {

            populate(key, data);

        });

    }

function populate(key, data) {

    var panel="#"+key+"_panel"; 
        $(panel).html("");
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            var eachrow = item + "<br>";
             $(panel).append(eachrow);
        });

    }
```

Second api response is coming as expected but it's not showing in div.

Comment: since we can't access your API, in order to reproduce this properly we will need an example of the data which comes back from the API for a given key. If there is a lot of data, just a small sample of it, enough to re-create the problem, would be sufficient.

Comment: api response is array of string like [app.prop, app_en.prop, app_es.prop, app_fr.prop]

Comment: how is "populateTable(data)" triggered, and what is the contents of "data" at that time? We would need that also to reproduce the problem. Otherwise we can't see what the HTML looks like which you are trying to insert the results of the API call into.